# Is there any alternative for FileSystemWatcher in .NET C#?

Tags: c#, file-watcher

I am new to .NET Core and currently working on a use case where I need to process the files in a directory.

The application is using the `FileSystemWatcher` class to monitor the directory(s).

Below is the code that I am using to monitor the directories.

```
private FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
private List<CustomFileEvent> custEventsList = new List();

private void MonitorDirectory(strinig dirName) 
{
    
    watcher.Path = dirName;
    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
    
    watcher.Filter = "*.*";
    
    // Add created event handler
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    //
    //watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

    // Setting the internal buffer size to 24kb. By default it is 8kb
    watcher.InternalBufferSize = 24000;

    // Begin watching.
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    
    watcher.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.All);
}

private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Event Occured");
    Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.FullPath} {e.ChangeType}");
    
    // Code to handle the file created event
    // Passing the parameters fileName, fullPath, dateTime, and size of the file
    CreateFileEvent(......)
    
}

private void CreateFileEvent(string fileName, string fullPath, DateTime timeStamp,long size) {
    // Code to create the File created event
    var customFileEvent = new CustomFileEvent()
    {
        FileName = fileName,
        FullPath = fullPath,
        TimeStamp = timeStamp,
        Size = size
    };
    
    custEventsList.Add(customFileEvent);
}

private void TimerFunction(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (custEventsList != null && custEventsList.Count != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Total events :: " + custEventsList .Count);

        foreach (var evnt in custEventsList)
        {
            ProcessEvent( ..... arguments to send the file watcher events);
        }
    }
    
    // Clear your file List.
    custEventsList = new List<CustomFileEvent>();  // CustomFileEvent is a custom class
}
```

Assuming the application is monitoring the folder C:\MyAppFiles\AppEvents
The TimerFunction is created to handle the events after each 20 secs interval.
The `ProcessEvent` method is actually used to send the file details to another Windows Service which processes the file and delete it.

With this code I am successfully able to process one file at a time and delete it. The problem occurs when I am trying to process multiple files using below steps.

1. Copy a FileData.txt to watching folder. The `Created` event occurs and OnChanged function get called.
2. The `CreateFileEvent` creates the custom event.
3. TimerFunction handle the events after each 20 secs.
4. Copy FileData_2.txt before 20 secs.
5. The folder is having 2 files for processing.
6. The code processes both the files and delete the files. The folder is empty now.
7. Now I placed another file FileData_3.txt
8. Found that `Created` event is not getting generated. And the file is not getting processed.

UPDATE: I observed that after processing the the file in ProcessEvent function, the FileSystemWatcher is getting disposed automatically. This happens only in case when I am trying to put multiple files for processing. In case of single file it works successfully.

Please advice.

Comment: Is the app _still_ running? What I've done with a similar watcher was to wrap it all in a Windows service and all the watcher does is _logs_ the changes (aka "events"). A _separate_ app (scheduled, e.g. Windows Task Scheduler) processes the logs and does whatever action a log represents (move, copy, delete, process, etc). Hth..

Comment: Why do you have `WaitForChanged()` there? I doubt you want a synch handler. You also don't want to block the event handler(s) with synchronous code. Do the processing in another thread. What is `CreateFileEvent()` actually doing? Did you add a *delayed operation* to try to avoid files blocked because still being written to?

Comment: The example lacks critical parts of the program. How is the timer created? How does the handler get the events?

Comment: But the events are still active while the app is active and They do not need to be handled in some specific time, they just fireing on change in the looked location. If you whant that they listening permanently the windows service or the worker service could be your solution (The WorkerService can be used for another OSs too). The events just need a active FileSystemWatcher.

Comment: @EdSF yes the app is still running and we are using the Windows service to monitor the folders and look for the files created events.

Comment: @Jimi CreateFileEvent() function is used to create the custom event class where we are providing the details of the event generated to process it.

Comment: @JonasH, The timer is created by using System.Timers.Timer class. So that we can process multiple file events after each time interval.

Comment: @spzvtbg Thanks for your reply. I think I will go with the approach that you are suggesting.

Comment: My problem is that after copying two files (one by one) and processing and deleting these two files the FileSystemWatcher stops generating events. It is not generating events for the next file that I paste into the folder. I tried to add ErrorEventHandler as well to see if there are any errors in watching the directory. But no luck!!! Even it does not generate any errors.

Comment: As mentioned, you have to remove  `watcher.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.All);` (btw, that method returns *something* and you're ignoring it. Don't call this method. Ever) and avoid, *at all costs*, to block the FSW's events, processing the watched files synchronously. This is the big issue almost everyone has. You simply cannot do that. Still obscure the reason why there's *timed something* (or an attempt of it). The files **must** be processed in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a complete solution, but you have a big issue with this code :

- Your FileSystemWatcher variable gets destroyed after each iteration in the foreach loop.

That enough is a problem as you have no idea if the object is still referenced somewhere. All the FileSystemWatcher you create should be held in an array or something like that that will not be destroyed after the call to your method (i.e. as instance variables).

Since you don't show the code that actually handles the event, it is hard to tell where the problem comes from exactly. But keep in mind that if your thread gets stuck in the OnChanged method, no other event will fire until you leave that method properly.

Please share the code for methods `CreateFileEvent` and `TimerFunction`.

EDIT:

You may want to look at [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netcore-3.1) .Net class as you have multiple threads manipulating the list and you pay no attention to thread safety.

Also, you do not have to call WaitForChanged and the end of your method, putting EnableRaisingEvent to true is enough.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have updated the post and that has the required code for CreateFileEvent and TimerFunction.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to resolve the problem.
Used the `ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);` as member variable and  `manualResetEvent.WaitOne();` into the function.

Below is the code

```
private FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
private List<CustomFileEvent> custEventsList = new List();

private readonly ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

private void MonitorDirectory(strinig dirName) 
{
    
    watcher.Path = dirName;
    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
    
    watcher.Filter = "*.*";
    
    // Add created event handler
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    //
    //watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

    // Setting the internal buffer size to 24kb. By default it is 8kb
    watcher.InternalBufferSize = 24000;

    // Begin watching.
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    
    // watcher.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.All);
    manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

Hope this will help to others who are facing same issue.